# Circular buffer for debug logging

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, embedded

I am working on implementing a in memory debug logging mechanism. The requirements are as follows

- The buffer for storing debug messages is fixed, lets say 4KB
- The debug messages written to the buffer are arbitrary in size could be 10 bytes or 2000 bytes or more
- The debug messages should be rotated once the buffer is full.
- The debug messages must be retrieved in the order it was inserted into the buffer.

I am thinking of implementing this as a single linked list with a muncher to collect buffers when all the buffers are utilized.

What do you guys think ? Any pointers and advice will be really appreciated.

0_l_0

Comment: Is that 4K for pointers or 4K for all text?

Comment: You don't need a linked list.  That list will waste too much memory, especially if you have a bunch of short debug messages.  All you need is a single pointer for tracking the start and another pointer for tracking the end of your 4K circular buffer.

Comment: And eat the first 2 bytes of each message with a length-prefix (if I understand your desired layout), or a single-byte (aka `0xFF`) noting end-of-message. This, assuming you want to discern one message from another, You need none of it if this is just a big chunk of rotating text.

Comment: Put an upper bound on the length of the messages (2048 bytes, perhaps).  You'll need to be able to tell how long each message is so that you can tell how many old messages you need to zap when you add a new one that has to overwrite pre-existing messages.  Also, why are you constrained to a 4 KiB buffer?  For many systems, 4 KiB is noise in the memory usage.

Comment: The question is tagged "embedded" making it entirely possible that 4KB is half the RAM in the system.  If going for a simple scheme, I'd do newline or null termination, and possibly a filter so that output starts at the beginning of an entire message, rather than randomly in the middle of one.

Comment: @MarkRansom  4K is for all text
I agree, but one of my goals is to keep debug message boundaries in tact. One option i am thinking of is using a special start of msg and end of msg

Comment: Thaks for the replies

@ TJD I agree, but one of my goals is to keep debug message boundaries in tact. One option i am thinking of is using a special start and end marker for messages.

@JonathanLeffler - Yup, 2048 is my upper bound. It is an embedded system and 4KiB is all I get :(

Also, this problem can be thought of as design of memory allocator. In that respect, I came across sralloc.c sralloc.h from microchip to be close to what I want. Will keep you guys posted.

Comment: You could just ignore the boundaries in your circular loop overwrite logic, but have your output code scan forward until it finds a terminator and only start outputting after that, so that it starts with a complete message or any message header information.  (and if your logging is asynchronous from your reporting, stop at a terminator, though you'll need to block logging temporarily while you find the start)

Comment: @ChrisStratton I thought of that too, but if "must be retrieved in the order it was sent" is a requirement, then the header would also need message numbers or something.  [start of frame][id][data][end of frame]...

Comment: @Ross in a dead simple implementation, the order of the messages in the buffer (once unwrapped by the readout code) is the order in in which the logging calls obtained whatever mutex was required to enter the critical section.  There could be slight differences between this and timestamps of when the logging was attempted, but for most applications that will not be important, and can be sorted out by manual review of the timestamps in the exceptional race cases, or a sort running on the displaying machine if it's a common issue.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I was insufficiently clear in my comment.  "ID" is only needed for when the buffer wraps around to the start and starts eating old messages.  At that point you're not certain which was first, as all you have is a pile of messages, not necessarily starting at [0] of the buffer.

Comment: Circular buffers generally have a pointer and a size, or two pointers.  Relative to those, you can know the ordinal age of any byte of data.  Without this, you wouldn't have any way to know where to write the next message, either.

Answer (score 3):

Thanx everyone for the replies. Here is the implementation I have finalized on.

- Every message inserted into the ring will be prefixed with the message length
- There will be a head and tail pointer, and ring_size.
- For every message to be written to ring buffer I will perform the following checks

  - Is there space in the ring buffer for the new message ?
  - Does the message require the head to be moved to make room for the new message to be inserted, if yes chomp the oldest messages by moving head till we have enough room for the new message. Now insert message and and update tail.
  - One other thing I have to consider is wraparounds while reading/writing the message from/to the buffer. For example when a new message to be inserted is exceeding the ring boundary, that's a special write operation with a wrap around when we reach end of buffer. Essentially, message reads/writes with wrap around result in two read/write operation. One write/read till the end of ring and one more read/write from the beginning of buffer.
- Since the head points to the oldest message and I can traverse the ring with the lengths prefixed to messages, hence ordering is not a problem.

Zero One
0_l_0

Comment: I am working on a similar problem/code, on the point of wraparound above, are you handling it with writing the log to a temp location and then getting the size?, or, when you get the log, you already know the size? (which kind of simplifies the problem). I use `vsprintf` and the only way for me to know the size is to print once and then check the size!

Comment: I know the size of the log message when the function receives it. I agree, that simplifies the logic.